# How to send Array & Set datatype data in AJAX call?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have this spring API

```
@RequestMapping(value="setentry/{userId}/{columnName}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> updateUserSetTypeFields(@PathVariable String userId, 
            @PathVariable String columnName, @RequestBody CollectionRequestParams entries ,
                HttpServletRequest request)
{
```

Here is `CollectionRequestParams`

```
public class CollectionRequestParams {
    private String[] arr;
    private Set set;

   // setter & getter
```

I am trying to call this API as :

```
$.ajax({
                url:"setEntry/123/111",
                headers:{"X-AccessKey":"token","X-deviceId":"123"},
                data:{"arr":['111','222']},
                type:"POST",contentType:"application/json"
            })
```

This is throwing `HTTP status 400` My question is how can i pass arguments for `arr` & `set` i.e sending `String[]` & `Set` datatype data ?

Comment: try to convert the data object to json string with `JSON.stringify`

Comment: I tried `data:{"arr":JSON.stringify(arr)},` and error is `Required List parameter 'arr' is not present`

Comment: See my answer. You have to stringify the whole json object.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you missed "arr" varliable in your controller.
I'm using List instead Array, next method:

```
@RequestParam(value = "arr[]", required = true) List<Integer> myList
```

in your case, it should be like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> updateUserSetTypeFields(@PathVariable String userId, @PathVariable String columnName, @RequestParam(value = "arr[]", required = true) List<Integer> yourList, HttpServletRequest request)
{ }
```

UPD for last example:
Java code:

```
public ResponseEntity test(@RequestParam(value = "arr[]", required = true) String[] arr) {}
```

ajax
          var arr=["Software Engineer","IT Analyst"];
            $.ajax({
                data:{arr:arr},

REMOVE dataType: json!

Comment: and how can I send `Set` data type from client side and read the same on server side ?

Comment: Did you try Set instead of List?

Comment: Required List parameter 'arr' is not present

Comment: Try to watch at request via Chrome in Developer mode, you will see your request

Comment: here is my request jquery ajax `var arr=["Software Engineer","IT Analyst"];  data:{"arr[]":JSON.stringify(arr)},dataType:'json',
                type:"POST",contentType:"application/json"` inside chrome dev mode it shows `arr%5B%5D=%5B%22Software+Engineer%22%2C%22IT+Analyst%22%5D`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@RequestBody` this means get the body of the request and try to parse and map it to the parameter class.

In your case you need a json like

`{"arr" : ["1", "asd", "45"], "set" : ["123", "222"]}` but this has to be the body of the request. Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"setEntry/123/111",
    headers:{"X-AccessKey":"token","X-deviceId":"123"},
    data: JSON.stringify({"arr":['111','222']}),
    type:"POST",contentType:"application/json"
})
```

You have to stringify the whole object.

Also don't use non generic Set, it's a bad practice. Change it to Set ot whatever type you need.

Comment: On server side i hv `@RequestParam(value = "arr", required = true) Set<String> entries` and client side `data:JSON.stringify({"arr":['111','222']}),dataType:'json',             type:"POST",contentType:"application/json" ` and i am getting `Required Set parameter 'arr' is not present`

Comment: In the question you have `@RequestBody CollectionRequestParams entries`. I don't see  `@RequestParam`  in the original question.

Comment: actually i was trying to do using `@RequestParam` so i am looking for solution using `@RequestParam`